# Manga where a genius student swaps bodies with a thug

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

I once read this manga years ago where a weak school nerd/genius who was getting bullied swapped body with a strong know thug/gangster/delinquent after I believe they collide into each others or something. I have been searching for this manga and haven't gotten a clue of what it is called.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this manga in full colour, or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be ***[Change Guy](https://myanimelist.net/manga/2977/Change_Guy)*** (AKA *Quantum Mistake*)...?

From MyAnimeList:

> It's nature vs. nurture when **a nerd swaps bodies with the toughest guy in school!** Tuji and Usoo have swapped...their bodies! After becoming the subjects of a mad scientist's experiment with her latest invention - the quantum teleporter - their bodies are switched, leaving only their minds and spirits intact. **Usoo, who was once a model student, must face the life of Tuji, a teenage menace.** Never having an enemy in his life, he now has to deal with the handful of Tuji's list, but will his kinder, gentler demeanor ward off his rivals? Or will survival determine his future? Will he become the hardened fighter that matches his new exterior?

Comment: @King - If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.